# How to copy data from a db2 database and insert in a sql database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms, db2

I have a SQL Server database and a DB2 database, I need to copy data from the DB2 database and insert into the SQL Server database with a button click.

What is the best way to do that?

The programming language I use is C# forms

Comment: You can use ADO.NET, here is the connection string for DB2. Server=myAddress:myPortNumber;Database=myDataBase;UID=myUsername;PWD=myPassword;

Comment: The best way is a matter of opinion.  My opinion is don't copy the data, use what you have.  Set up a linked server on Sql Server to DB2.

Comment: I agree with Dan Bracuk , use a linked server. I would also use T-SQL for this kind of job, put the code inside a stored procedure and call it through the button click

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Im going to try it.